# Why do I get js execution errors with angular.dart 0.10 and ng-view?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I just migrated to [angular-0.10.0](http://blog.angulardart.org/2014/04/angulardart-0100-ostemad-teleportation.html). My application works as expected in *Dartium* but in js through *dart2js* I get the follow unminified error in web console :

```
No getter for 'ctrl'.

STACKTRACE:
Error
    at dart.wrapException (http://localhost:8080/app/main.dart.js:2390:15)
    at StaticClosureMap.lookupGetter$1 (http://localhost:8080/app/main.dart.js:8926:17)
    at DynamicParserBackend.newAccessScope$1 (http://localhost:8080/app/main.dart.js:7177:21)
    at DynamicParserImpl.parseAccessOrCallScope$0 (http://localhost:8080/app/main.dart.js:7531:29)
    at DynamicParserImpl.parsePrimary$0 (http://localhost:8080/app/main.dart.js:7507:21)
    at DynamicParserImpl.parseAccessOrCallMember$0 (http://localhost:8080/app/main.dart.js:7464:21)
    at DynamicParserImpl.parsePrefix$0 (http://localhost:8080/app/main.dart.js:7460:21)
    at DynamicParserImpl.parseMultiplicative$0 (http://localhost:8080/app/main.dart.js:7439:21)
    at DynamicParserImpl.parseAdditive$0 (http://localhost:8080/app/main.dart.js:7428:21)
    at DynamicParserImpl.parseRelational$0 (http://localhost:8080/app/main.dart.js:7413:21)
```

The `pubspec.yaml`

```yaml
name: app
version: 0.0.1-dev
dependencies:
  angular: any
  browser: any
dev_dependencies:
  unittest: any
transformers:
- angular
```

The controller :

```dart
@Controller(selector: '[myCtrl]', publishAs: 'ctrl')
class MyController {
  String search = 'test';
}
```

The html template :

```html
<div myCtrl>
  <input ng-model="ctrl.search"></input>
  {{ ctrl.search }}
</div>
```

The error only appear inside an `<ng-view>`. If I add the above html directly in the main html the js error does not appear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pavel Jbanov indicates in [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular-dart/R_4CrZcUnSk/pGVO4gJyPlgJ) :

> I believe [expression_generator](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fangular%2Fangular.dart%2Fblob%2Fmaster%2Flib%2Ftools%2Ftransformer%2Fexpression_generator.dart&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNHo6b31k6Wr6qc26TfrJc6n5RVWig) transformer is unable to discover your template file, so you might need to manually include it: https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/blob/master/lib/tools/transformer/options.dart#L17

and further :

> The transformer will hopefully get better at identifying template files so you don't have to manually list them. Right now, afaik, it only picks up template files of components.

So for now you have to manually add all untracked html templates inside your `pubspec.yaml` like this in the `html_files` section :

```yaml
name: app
version: 0.0.1-dev
dependencies:
  angular: any
  browser: any
dev_dependencies:
  unittest: any
transformers:
- angular:
    html_files:
    - web/template1.html
    - web/template2.html
    - web/template3.html
```